# Why won't my script update my div dynamically like it's supposed to?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #000000;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sleep(ms)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
}
function update() {
    while (0 < 1) {<?php $contents = file_get_contents("my url here"); 
    ?>
        var count = <?php echo $contents ?>;
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = count;
        sleep(1500);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload=update()>
<iframe id="iframe" src="my url" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
<table width=100% height=100%>
<tr height=80%>
<td width=100%>
<center>
<div id="div"></div>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When viewing the source code in-browser, the `var` is set correctly, but it won't set the content of the `div`. I am positive that the url the PHP script is pointing to is accurate and contains only a script to grep a number from an external page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the page as it's run without the PHP in it please? (IE, just load the page, view source then copy that in).  Also, your HTML elements are in my opinion badly named, calling them 'div' and 'iframe' are ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop/sleep, you should use setInterval()

Comment: btw.. never use loops to simulate sleep .. the system is doing quite the opposite than sleeping in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the value of `file_get_contents("my url here")` yields `42` (for example), you are aware that you're creating an infinite loop which will set the content of `#div` to `42` over and over again every 1.5 seconds? I.e., `var count` will always, constantly be `42` and won't change, since PHP is evaluated only *once* on the server.

Furthermore I would suspect that your `sleep` function could pose a bit of a problem, since it creates another tight loop. I wouldn't be surprised if this script simply blocked the browser without ever updating anything since it's caught in an infinite loop. The way to delay execution in Javascript is to use `window.setTimeout` or `window.setInterval`.

I guess what you're looking for is an AJAX solution of some kind, if you would tell us what it is you want to do. Since you're including jQuery (without actually using it), you should have a look at [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), coupled with a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to update the `div` periodically.

Something like:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.get("my url here", function (data) {
        $('#div').html(data);
    });
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant to use jQuery but never did... I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, why isn't it running... your `onload` needs quotes:

```
<body onload="update()">
```

but the others have posted better ways to go about it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = <?php echo $contents ?>;
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = count;
```

You are asking the webserver for variable $contents through php, which will always be a static number unless you reload the page. Try using jQuery, as the poster above mentioned.